# Kendo UI Server side wrappers

Tags: nuget, kendo-ui, nuget-package

Is there a nuget package for the Kendo UI server side wrappers? I know there is a nuget package that installs jquery + all the kendo js files but it doesn't include the kendo.mvc.dll which is what I care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telerik is not planning to create a Nuget package for Kendo UI server side wrappers. Here is the discussion topic dated back in July 2012:

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/nuget-install-for-kendoui-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

We (Telerik) may create a Nuget package for Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC once we implement a self-hosted nuget service. This is required for license validation because Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC is a commercial product. In a word this is not completely off the table but needs some infrastructural changes. Still no clear deadline.