# Installing Kendo UI from NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm currently trying to install Kendo UI from NuGet and noticed an issue.  I cannot find the KendoUI.dll to reference.  Is it in this package, and if not, is there a way to get around that to use it within Views?

Answer (score 3):

This now possible. See the release article [here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-kendo-ui-q3-2015-available-now), in the section Private NuGet Server and Feed.

The Kendo Nuget url is https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget you will need your Kendo account password to download it.

Answer (score 2):

The files you are looking for are part of the Kendo UI [server-side wrappers](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-02-19/what-the-kendo-ui-mvc-server-wrappers-are-and-why-you-should-be-using-them---part-1) package. That package is (currently) not available via NuGet.  According to Telerik in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967739/385996):

> We (Telerik) may create a Nuget package for Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC
>   once we implement a self-hosted nuget service. This is required for
>   license validation because Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC is a commercial
>   product. In a word this is not completely off the table but needs some
>   infrastructural changes. Still no clear deadline.